# I cannot get the latest meteor todos example chimp acceptance test to work on mac osx 10.11.16 with chrome Version 59.0.3071.86

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, meteor, chimp.js

I am running on OSX 10.11.6 with Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I have downloaded and installed the latest meteor todos app, and following the tutorial performed the unit and integration testing examples successfully. When I try the chimp acceptance test and use --debug in the output I get the first log below which indicates a browser incompatibility. After changing the 
node_modules/chimp/dist/bin/default.js seleniumStandaloneOptions 
like this (notice version: 2.30)...

```
  seleniumStandaloneOptions: {
    // check for more recent versions of selenium here:
    // http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
    version: '3.0.1',
    baseURL: 'https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com',
    drivers: {
      chrome: {
        // check for more recent versions of chrome driver here:
        // http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
        //version: '2.25',
        version: '2.30',
        arch: process.arch,
        baseURL: 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com'
      },
```

.....
I get the second log below. 
I do see a window flash briefly then go away - too fast to see what it is doing. There is no output on the meteor console either. I have tried many different options but cannot seem to make this work, and do not seem to know how to debug it. Do any of you have any other ideas or debugging help? The browser can exercise the todos app on localhost:3000 with no apparent problems. There are no console errors in the browser while it is accessing the todos app. 
I would really appreciate any insight anyone has. Thanks.

First log.....

```
$chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --test --mocha --path=tests --debug
[chimp] Chimp options are { watch: false,
  watchTags: '@watch,@focus',
  domainSteps: null,
  e2eSteps: null,
  fullDomain: false,
  domainOnly: false,
  e2eTags: '@e2e',
  watchWithPolling: false,
  server: false,
  serverPort: 8060,
  serverHost: 'localhost',
  sync: true,
  offline: false,
  showXolvioMessages: true,
  'fail-when-no-tests-run': false,
  path: './features',
  format: 'pretty',
  tags: '~@ignore',
  singleSnippetPerFile: true,
  recommendedFilenameSeparator: '_',
  chai: false,
  screenshotsOnError: false,
  screenshotsPath: '.screenshots',
  captureAllStepScreenshots: false,
  saveScreenshotsToDisk: true,
  saveScreenshotsToReport: false,
  jsonOutput: null,
  compiler: 'js:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/babel-register.js',
  conditionOutput: true,
  browser: null,
  platform: 'ANY',
  name: '',
  user: '',
  key: '',
  port: null,
  host: null,
  webdriverio: 
   { desiredCapabilities: {},
     logLevel: 'silent',
     host: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 4444,
     path: '/wd/hub',
     baseUrl: null,
     coloredLogs: true,
     screenshotPath: null,
     waitforTimeout: 500,
     waitforInterval: 250 },
  seleniumStandaloneOptions: 
   { version: '3.0.1',
     baseURL: 'https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com',
     drivers: { chrome: [Object], ie: [Object], firefox: [Object] } },
  noSessionReuse: false,
  simianResultEndPoint: 'api.simian.io/v1.0/result',
  simianAccessToken: false,
  simianResultBranch: null,
  simianRepositoryId: null,
  mocha: false,
  mochaCommandLineOptions: { bail: true },
  mochaConfig: 
   { tags: '',
     grep: null,
     timeout: 60000,
     reporter: 'spec',
     slow: 10000,
     useColors: true },
  jasmine: false,
  jasmineConfig: 
   { specDir: '.',
     specFiles: [ '**/*@(_spec|-spec|Spec).@(js|jsx)' ],
     helpers: [ 'support/**/*.@(js|jsx)' ],
     stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: false,
     random: false },
  jasmineReporterConfig: {},
  ddp: false,
  serverExecuteTimeout: 10000,
  phantom_w: 1280,
  phantom_h: 1024,
  phantom_ignoreSSLErrors: false,
  log: 'info',
  debug: false,
  seleniumDebug: null,
  debugCucumber: null,
  debugBrkCucumber: null,
  debugMocha: null,
  debugBrkMocha: null }

Chimp version:  0.49.0
ChromeDriver version:  ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262)
Java version:  java version "1.8.0_66", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
Selenium version:  3.0.1
Selenium drivers version:  chrome: 2.25, ie: 2.50.0, firefox: 0.11.1
OS version:  Darwin 15.6.0
Node version:  v6.11.0
[chimp][browserdriver] starting process
[chimp][browserdriver.stdout] Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262) on port 52347
Only local connections are allowed.

[chimp][browserdriver] started successfully
[chimp][browserdriver] kill called on browserdriver process with pid 48946
[chimp][browserdriver] checking if process exists
[chimp][browserdriver] browserdriver process exists, killing it with SIGTERM
[chimp][browserdriver] waiting for process to die (0/10)
[chimp][browserdriver] process is dead
Browser version:  chrome undefined

[chimp] Running...
[chimp] interrupting
[chimp] no processes to interrupt
[chimp][chromedriver] starting process
[chimp][chromedriver.stdout] Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262) on port 52347
Only local connections are allowed.

[chimp][chromedriver] started successfully
[chimp][mocha] Running...


[chimp][helper] Using the chai-expect assertion library
[chimp][ddp] creating DDP wrapper
[chimp][ddp] Connecting to DDP server { host: 'localhost',
  port: '3000',
  ssl: false,
  path: undefined,
  autoReconnect: true,
  autoReconnectTimer: 500,
  maintainCollections: true,
  ddpVersion: '1',
  useSockJs: true }
[chimp][ddp] creating DDP wrapper
[chimp][ddp] Connecting to DDP server { host: 'localhost',
  port: '3000',
  ssl: false,
  path: undefined,
  autoReconnect: true,
  autoReconnectTimer: 500,
  maintainCollections: true,
  ddpVersion: '1',
  useSockJs: true }
[chimp][helper] getting browser
[chimp][session-manager-factory] options are { host: 'localhost',
  port: 52347,
  user: undefined,
  key: undefined,
  browser: 'chrome',
  deviceName: undefined }
[chimp][session-manager] created a new SessionManager
[chimp][helper] webdriverioOptions are  {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","name":""},"logLevel":"verbose","host":"localhost","port":52347,"path":"/wd/hub","baseUrl":null,"coloredLogs":true,"screenshotPath":null,"waitforTimeout":500,"waitforInterval":250,"sync":true}
[chimp][session-manager] creating webdriver remote 
[chimp][session-manager] checking connection to selenium server
[15:10:45]  COMMAND GET      "/wd/hub/status"
[15:10:45]  DATA        {}
[15:10:45]  RESULT      {"build":{"version":"alpha"},"os":{"arch":"x86_64","name":"Mac OS X","version":"10.11.6"}}
[chimp][session-manager] Connection to the to selenium server verified
[chimp][session-manager] watch mode is false, not reusing a session
[chimp][hooks] init browser
[chimp][hooks] init browser callback
[15:10:45]  COMMAND POST     "/wd/hub/session"
[15:10:45]  DATA        {"desiredCapabilities":{"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"handlesAlerts":true,"rotatable":true,"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","name":"","loggingPrefs":{"browser":"ALL","driver":"ALL"},"requestOrigins":{"url":"http://webdriver.io","version":"4.6.2","name":"webdriverio"}}}
[chimp][helper] setupBrowserAndDDP had error
{ Error: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0
    at initBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:189:43)
    at Object.setupBrowserAndDDP (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:264:7)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/mocha/mocha-helper.js:13:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/utils/fiberize.js:29:22
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
  message: 'session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)',
  type: 'RuntimeError',
  seleniumStack: 
   { status: 33,
     type: 'SessionNotCreatedException',
     message: 'A new session could not be created.',
     orgStatusMessage: 'session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)' } }
Error: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0
    at initBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:189:43)
    at Object.setupBrowserAndDDP (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:264:7)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/mocha/mocha-helper.js:13:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/utils/fiberize.js:29:22
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
[chimp][mocha] Closed with code 2
[chimp][mocha] Mocha not in a stopping state
[chimp] Finished running async processes with errors
[chimp] run complete with errors Mocha failed
[chimp] interrupting
[chimp] 2 processes to interrupt
[chimp][mocha] interrupting mocha
[chimp][mocha] kill called on mocha process with pid 48957
[chimp][mocha] checking if process exists
[chimp][mocha] mocha process does not exists, ignoring
[chimp][chromedriver] interrupt called
[chimp][chromedriver] stopping process
[chimp][chromedriver] kill called on chromedriver process with pid 48956
[chimp][chromedriver] checking if process exists
[chimp][chromedriver] chromedriver process exists, killing it with SIGTERM
Mocha failed
Error in chimp init Mocha failed
```

.......
Second log with chromedriver v 2.30.....

```
$chimp --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --test --mocha --path=tests --debug
[chimp] Chimp options are { watch: false,
  watchTags: '@watch,@focus',
  domainSteps: null,
  e2eSteps: null,
  fullDomain: false,
  domainOnly: false,
  e2eTags: '@e2e',
  watchWithPolling: false,
  server: false,
  serverPort: 8060,
  serverHost: 'localhost',
  sync: true,
  offline: false,
  showXolvioMessages: true,
  'fail-when-no-tests-run': false,
  path: './features',
  format: 'pretty',
  tags: '~@ignore',
  singleSnippetPerFile: true,
  recommendedFilenameSeparator: '_',
  chai: false,
  screenshotsOnError: false,
  screenshotsPath: '.screenshots',
  captureAllStepScreenshots: false,
  saveScreenshotsToDisk: true,
  saveScreenshotsToReport: false,
  jsonOutput: null,
  compiler: 'js:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/babel-register.js',
  conditionOutput: true,
  browser: null,
  platform: 'ANY',
  name: '',
  user: '',
  key: '',
  port: null,
  host: null,
  webdriverio: 
   { desiredCapabilities: {},
     logLevel: 'silent',
     host: '127.0.0.1',
     port: 4444,
     path: '/wd/hub',
     baseUrl: null,
     coloredLogs: true,
     screenshotPath: null,
     waitforTimeout: 500,
     waitforInterval: 250 },
  seleniumStandaloneOptions: 
   { version: '3.0.1',
     baseURL: 'https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com',
     drivers: { chrome: [Object], ie: [Object], firefox: [Object] } },
  noSessionReuse: false,
  simianResultEndPoint: 'api.simian.io/v1.0/result',
  simianAccessToken: false,
  simianResultBranch: null,
  simianRepositoryId: null,
  mocha: false,
  mochaCommandLineOptions: { bail: true },
  mochaConfig: 
   { tags: '',
     grep: null,
     timeout: 60000,
     reporter: 'spec',
     slow: 10000,
     useColors: true },
  jasmine: false,
  jasmineConfig: 
   { specDir: '.',
     specFiles: [ '**/*@(_spec|-spec|Spec).@(js|jsx)' ],
     helpers: [ 'support/**/*.@(js|jsx)' ],
     stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: false,
     random: false },
  jasmineReporterConfig: {},
  ddp: false,
  serverExecuteTimeout: 10000,
  phantom_w: 1280,
  phantom_h: 1024,
  phantom_ignoreSSLErrors: false,
  log: 'info',
  debug: false,
  seleniumDebug: null,
  debugCucumber: null,
  debugBrkCucumber: null,
  debugMocha: null,
  debugBrkMocha: null }

Chimp version:  0.49.0
ChromeDriver version:  ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262)
Java version:  java version "1.8.0_66", Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17), Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
Selenium version:  3.0.1
Selenium drivers version:  chrome: 2.25, ie: 2.50.0, firefox: 0.11.1
OS version:  Darwin 15.6.0
Node version:  v6.11.0
[chimp][browserdriver] starting process
[chimp][browserdriver.stdout] Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262) on port 52418
Only local connections are allowed.

[chimp][browserdriver] started successfully
[chimp][browserdriver] kill called on browserdriver process with pid 49380
[chimp][browserdriver] checking if process exists
[chimp][browserdriver] browserdriver process exists, killing it with SIGTERM
[chimp][browserdriver] waiting for process to die (0/10)
[chimp][browserdriver] process is dead
Browser version:  chrome undefined

[chimp] Running...
[chimp] interrupting
[chimp] no processes to interrupt
[chimp][chromedriver] starting process
[chimp][chromedriver.stdout] Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262) on port 52418
Only local connections are allowed.

[chimp][chromedriver] started successfully
[chimp][mocha] Running...


[chimp][helper] Using the chai-expect assertion library
[chimp][ddp] creating DDP wrapper
[chimp][ddp] Connecting to DDP server { host: 'localhost',
  port: '3000',
  ssl: false,
  path: undefined,
  autoReconnect: true,
  autoReconnectTimer: 500,
  maintainCollections: true,
  ddpVersion: '1',
  useSockJs: true }
[chimp][ddp] creating DDP wrapper
[chimp][ddp] Connecting to DDP server { host: 'localhost',
  port: '3000',
  ssl: false,
  path: undefined,
  autoReconnect: true,
  autoReconnectTimer: 500,
  maintainCollections: true,
  ddpVersion: '1',
  useSockJs: true }
[chimp][helper] getting browser
[chimp][session-manager-factory] options are { host: 'localhost',
  port: 52418,
  user: undefined,
  key: undefined,
  browser: 'chrome',
  deviceName: undefined }
[chimp][session-manager] created a new SessionManager
[chimp][helper] webdriverioOptions are  {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","name":""},"logLevel":"verbose","host":"localhost","port":52418,"path":"/wd/hub","baseUrl":null,"coloredLogs":true,"screenshotPath":null,"waitforTimeout":500,"waitforInterval":250,"sync":true}
[chimp][session-manager] creating webdriver remote 
[chimp][session-manager] checking connection to selenium server
[15:16:54]  COMMAND GET      "/wd/hub/status"
[15:16:54]  DATA        {}
[15:16:54]  RESULT      {"build":{"version":"alpha"},"os":{"arch":"x86_64","name":"Mac OS X","version":"10.11.6"}}
[chimp][session-manager] Connection to the to selenium server verified
[chimp][session-manager] watch mode is false, not reusing a session
[chimp][hooks] init browser
[chimp][hooks] init browser callback
[15:16:54]  COMMAND POST     "/wd/hub/session"
[15:16:54]  DATA        {"desiredCapabilities":{"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"handlesAlerts":true,"rotatable":true,"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","name":"","loggingPrefs":{"browser":"ALL","driver":"ALL"},"requestOrigins":{"url":"http://webdriver.io","version":"4.6.2","name":"webdriverio"}}}
[chimp][helper] setupBrowserAndDDP had error
{ Error: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0
    at initBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:189:43)
    at Object.setupBrowserAndDDP (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:264:7)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/mocha/mocha-helper.js:13:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/utils/fiberize.js:29:22
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
  message: 'session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)',
  type: 'RuntimeError',
  seleniumStack: 
   { status: 33,
     type: 'SessionNotCreatedException',
     message: 'A new session could not be created.',
     orgStatusMessage: 'session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)' } }
Error: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0
    at initBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:189:43)
    at Object.setupBrowserAndDDP (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:264:7)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/mocha/mocha-helper.js:13:15)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/utils/fiberize.js:29:22
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
[chimp][mocha] Closed with code 2
[chimp][mocha] Mocha not in a stopping state
[chimp] Finished running async processes with errors
[chimp] run complete with errors Mocha failed
[chimp] interrupting
[chimp] 2 processes to interrupt
[chimp][mocha] interrupting mocha
[chimp][mocha] kill called on mocha process with pid 49391
[chimp][mocha] checking if process exists
[chimp][mocha] mocha process does not exists, ignoring
[chimp][chromedriver] interrupt called
[chimp][chromedriver] stopping process
[chimp][chromedriver] kill called on chromedriver process with pid 49390
[chimp][chromedriver] checking if process exists
[chimp][chromedriver] chromedriver process exists, killing it with SIGTERM
Mocha failed
Error in chimp init Mocha failed
```

.......

I really want to get chimp working in order to implement acceptance testing on a significant meteor project that we are using in my group.

Failing getting chimp to work, if anyone knows of a better way to do automated acceptance testing on a meteor app I would appreciate that insight as well. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using these versions.

Comment: $node -v
v6.11.0
$npm -v
5.0.3

Comment: Hi. There is not enough information to help. Can you show the full log in a gist.github.com please?

Comment: I thought this was the full log. I used "-- debug" on the chimp command. Is there a way to get a better log? I just started using chimp, actually.

Comment: I am working through the chimp debugging section in the chimp documentation using node-inspector If I can find other details I will put them in a comment, or gist,or wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get Chrome to work but I could get safari to work, after uninstalling and reinstalling chimp and using --browser=safari in the scripts block of the package.json (or on the cli invoking chimp with npm.)
so ...

```
$chimp -v
0.49.0
$npm -v
5.0.3
$node -v
v6.11.0
$chimp --mocha --test --path=tests --debug --ddp=http://localhost:3000 --browser=safari
```

works.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Feel free to join the Xolv.io/community for more help from other Chimp users

Comment: Thanks, I will, I am very impressed with Chimp at the moment.